# Get all text from a Div after a '-' up until the first character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a function that will find an instance of text within a div and console.log all text that is after the '-' character. After the '-' character there are sometimes spaces and tabs, so I want to remove these up until the first text character. Here's what I have so far (that is not working at all):

```
var countryData = $(".countries-title").next().text();

//var regex = /(?<= - ).*/g;
let stringArray = countryData.replace(/\t/g, '').split('\r\n');
console.log(stringArray);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the string in `countryData` and whats the expected value of `stringArray` ?

Comment: `\s*` should match any number of spaces and tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log('here is a     -     whole bunch of text'.match(/-\s*(.*)$/)[1])` will log out "whole bunch of text". Is that along the lines of what you are looking for? Let me know if you want me to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to maintain all hyphens and formatting after the first hyphen and subsequent spaces you could use:

```
let textAfterHyphen = countryData.replace(/\s*-\s*/, '');
```

Comment: This will remove the hyphen and spaces around it. I don't think the OP wants to keep the text before the hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood all but here you have my solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function returnString() {
  $("#click-target").on("click",function(){
    var newString = [];
    var resultString = [];
    var onlyChar =$(".target").text();
    newString = onlyChar.split("");
    for(var i = 0; i < newString.length; i++){
      if(newString[i] == "-"){
        resultString = newString.slice(i+1,newString.length).join("");
      }
    }
    var k = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < resultString.length; j++){
      if(resultString.charCodeAt(j) > 64 && resultString.charCodeAt(j) < 91){
        k += j;
      } 
    }
   
    console.log(resultString.slice(k,resultString.length));
     
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target">Text-      *^^^***Text to display</div>
<button id ="click-target">Click</button>
```